# canvas size not getting same as video size in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, video

I am trying to set canvas on video but canvas size not getting same as video size ,
I have provide video size in % like
height 50%,
width 50%
then how we can set canvas of same size on video
Expecting same size of canvas as same of video size

Comment: is your canvas parent of video component? If so try to set canvas size as hieght: auto and width: fit-content

Comment: Please show relevant HTML and CSS. We cannot help without just guessing at the moment.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.